# Seemingly unrelated line prevents input box from being editable

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a svelte component that shows a list of preferences and allows them to be edited and new ones to be added. It is ordered into to listed for the preference names and preference values. Setting the value of `file_prefs_values` has no problem but if I even set the value of `file_prefs_keys` then suddenly my input boxes become frozen and I can not type in them but can still focus the input boxes and select text inside them.

I have attempted to move the extra reactivity code to a seperate function:

```js
$: () => {
  file_prefs_values = file_prefs_values;
  file_prefs_keys = file_prefs_keys;
}
```

But this causes the same error. I believe this error occurs if my code, at any point, attempts to directly set the value of this variable (`file_prefs_keys`).

My code is here if it helps:

```html
<script>
  import { input } from "../assets/utils.js";

  let file_prefs_keys = all().filter((k) => k.startsWith("extension-"));
  $: file_prefs_values = file_prefs_keys.map((k) => localStorage.getItem(k));

  $: file_prefs_keys.forEach((p, i) => {
    localStorage.setItem(p, file_prefs_values[i]);
  })

  async function newPref() {
    const ext = await input("Preferences", "Enter the file extension to add");

    localStorage.setItem("extension-" + ext, "");
  
    file_prefs_values = [...file_prefs_values, ""];
    // file_prefs_keys = [...file_prefs_keys,  "extension-" + ext]; // ERROR - cannot change input
    file_prefs_keys.push("extension-" + ext); // ERROR - not reactive, any extra code to make reactive has above problem
  }
  
</script>

<section>
  <div>
  {#each file_prefs_keys as pref}
    <span>
      {pref}
    </span>
    <br />
  {/each}
  </div>
  <div>
  {#each file_prefs_values as pref}
    <input bind:value={pref} />
    <br />
  {/each}
  </div>
</section>
<button on:click={newPref}>+</button>

<style>
  STYLES HERE
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of having two lists that depend on each other, just use one.

E.g.

```html
<script>
  const all = () =>
    Array.from({ length: localStorage.length },
    (_, i) => localStorage.key(i)
  );

  let preferences = all()
    .filter(k => k.startsWith('extension-'))
    .map(key => ({ key, value: localStorage.getItem(key) }));

  $: preferences.forEach(p => localStorage.setItem(p.key, p.value));

  async function newPref() {
    const ext = prompt('Enter the file extension to add');
    preferences = [...preferences, { key: 'extension-' + ext, value: '' }]
  }
</script>

<section>
  <div>
    {#each preferences as { key }}
      <!-- If something is a label, use a label. -->
      <label for="input-{key}">{key}</label>
      <br />
    {/each}
  </div>
  <div>
    {#each preferences as { key, value }}
      <input id="input-{key}" bind:value />
      <br />
    {/each}
  </div>
</section>
<button on:click={newPref}>+</button>
```

There is no need to add the value to local storage on adding the item. The reactive statement will take care of that. (Though currently it will write all items every time. If you want something more granular, extract things to a child component that only handles one key/input.)

[Labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) should be associated with inputs for accessibility, otherwise people using a screen reader will not know what they are even supposed to input.